# Angular FormGroup populate from JSON response

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I had to create a form that could handle 3 levels of nested form arrays, defined like so:

```
export class Task {
  type        : string;
  description : string;
  role        : string;
  resources   : string[];
}

export class Phase {
  name  : string;
  tasks : Task[];
}

export class Module {
  name   : string;
  phases : Phase[];
}

export class Structure {
  modules : Module[];
}
```

I followed  [this tutorial](https://medium.com/hashtaagco/3-levels-of-nested-form-arrays-including-reactive-validations-we-decided-to-go-inception-mode-on-4fffe667fb2a) and was able to implement it by assigning the value of my FormGroup to my form

```
  techniqueStruct : FormGroup;

  create() {

    this.form.structure = Object.assign({}, this.techniqueStruct.value);

    this.http.post<Technique>(`techniques`, this.form).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.toastr.success('Technique successfully created.', 'Success');
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      },
      err => this.handleError(err)
    );

  }
```

Now that I want to do a `PUT` request and edit the `Structure`, I have to populate all the form fields but I'm having trouble with `Structure` objects that have multiple `Module` objects.

```
this.techniqueStruct.setValue({
  modules: this.form.structure.modules
})
```

The above call will only populate the at index 0 and will throw the error

`ERROR Error: "Cannot find form control at index 1"`

How can I make sure every index is populated?

**EDIT - FormGroup **

```
  form  : Partial<Technique> = {
    name                  : "",
    description           : "",
    rules                 : [],
    delivery_mode         : [],
    interaction           : [],
    interrelationship     : [],
    motivation            : [],
    participation         : [],
    performance           : [],
    resolution_scope      : [],
    feedback_use          : [],
    target_audience       : [],
    learning_objectives   : [],
    affective_objectives  : [],
    social_objectives     : [],
    structure             : null
  };

  ngOnInit() {

    this.createHandler();

    this.getAttributes();

    this.techniqueStruct = this.fb.group({
      'modules': this.fb.array([
        this.initMod()
      ])
    });

    this.sub = this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      this.populateForm();
    });

  }
  initMod() {
    return this.fb.group({
      'name': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'phases': this.fb.array([
        this.initPhase()
      ])
    });
  }

  initPhase() {
    return this.fb.group({
      'name': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'tasks': this.fb.array([
        this.initTask()
      ])
    });
  }

  initTask() {
    return this.fb.group({
      'type': '',
      'description': '',
      'role': '',
      'resources': []
    })
  }


  addMod() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.techniqueStruct.controls['modules'];
    control.push(this.initMod());
  }

  addPhase(imod) {
    const control = (<FormArray>this.techniqueStruct.controls['modules']).at(imod).get('phases') as FormArray;
    control.push(this.initPhase());
  }

  addTask(imod, ipha) {
    const control = ((<FormArray>this.techniqueStruct.controls['modules']).at(imod).get('phases') as FormArray).at(ipha).get('tasks') as FormArray;
    control.push(this.initTask());
  }

  deleteMod(index) {
    let control = <FormArray>this.techniqueStruct.controls['modules'];
    control.removeAt(index)
  }

  deletePhase(imod, ipha) {
    const control = (<FormArray>this.techniqueStruct.controls['modules']).at(imod).get('phases') as FormArray;
    control.removeAt(ipha);
  }

  deleteTask(imod, ipha, itask) {
    const control = ((<FormArray>this.techniqueStruct.controls['modules']).at(imod).get('phases') as FormArray).at(ipha).get('tasks') as FormArray;
    control.removeAt(itask);
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code in a stackblitz somewhere? Specifically, I need to see the exact shape of the FormGroup. All I see is: ```techniqueStruct : FormGroup;```, but I don't see it ever initialized.

Comment: I've updated my post with the code for initializing the FormGroup. It follows the same shape as the `Structure` object. One strucute has at least one `Module`, each `Module` has a name and at least one `Phase`, each `Phase` has a name and at least one `Task`, each task with 3 `string` fields and one `string` array.

Comment: you should fill all form arrays with empty controls before calling setValue(). assuming this.form.structure.modules has 6 modules in it, and each module having 5 phases; you should call addMod() 6 times, then for each of those 6 modules you should fill phases array with empty controls by calling addPhase() 5 times and so on... you have a pretty complicated form structure here so seeing whole code in action in a stackblitz would make it a lot easier to help.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, filling the form arrays with the sufficient number of empty controls solved the problem, obviously it wasn't able to populate them if there was no "space" left for the remainder. I just had to call addMod() for each remaining module. Thanks a lot for the help.